Как генерировать avi файл?
Мне нужно создавать avi файл, заполняя его структуру и записывать в него кадры. Как я могу это сделать?
Может есть какой то более строгий мануал по созданию avi файла? Желательно использовать стандартные библиотеки по типу Windows.h и Vfw.h
Заполнял поля структур avi файла, которые определены в Vfw.h и записывал данные через fwrite согласно документации microsoft, но при открытии файла оказывается, что файл поврежден.

Найденный материал (в качестве идей и основы, разбирайтесь с ним сами):
#include <windows.h>
#include <vfw.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "vfw32.lib")

void CreateAVIFile(const char* filename) {
    PAVIFILE aviFile;
    PAVISTREAM aviStream;
    AVISTREAMINFO streamInfo;
    AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS compressOptions;
    AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS* compressOptionsArray[1] = { &compressOptions };
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bmpInfoHeader;

    // Инициализация библиотеки AVI
    AVIFileInit();

    // Создание AVI файла
    if (AVIFileOpen(&aviFile, filename, OF_WRITE | OF_CREATE, NULL) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Не удалось создать AVI файл." << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    // Заполнение структуры AVISTREAMINFO
    ZeroMemory(&streamInfo, sizeof(streamInfo));
    streamInfo.fccType = streamtypeVIDEO;
    streamInfo.fccHandler = 0;
    streamInfo.dwScale = 1;
    streamInfo.dwRate = 30; // 30 кадров в секунду
    streamInfo.dwSuggestedBufferSize = 0;
    SetRect(&streamInfo.rcFrame, 0, 0, 640, 480);

    // Создание AVI потока
    if (AVIFileCreateStream(aviFile, &aviStream, &streamInfo) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Не удалось создать AVI поток." << std::endl;
        AVIFileRelease(aviFile);
        return;
    }

    // Заполнение структуры BITMAPINFOHEADER
    ZeroMemory(&bmpInfoHeader, sizeof(bmpInfoHeader));
    bmpInfoHeader.biSize = sizeof(bmpInfoHeader);
    bmpInfoHeader.biWidth = 640;
    bmpInfoHeader.biHeight = 480;
    bmpInfoHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    bmpInfoHeader.biBitCount = 24;
    bmpInfoHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;

    // Настройка параметров сжатия
    ZeroMemory(&compressOptions, sizeof(compressOptions));
    compressOptions.fccType = streamtypeVIDEO;
    compressOptions.fccHandler = 0;
    compressOptions.dwKeyFrameEvery = 1;
    compressOptions.dwQuality = 10000;
    compressOptions.dwFlags = AVICOMPRESSF_VALID;

    // Создание сжатого AVI потока
    if (AVIMakeCompressedStream(&aviStream, aviStream, &compressOptions, NULL) != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Не удалось создать сжатый AVI поток." << std::endl;
        AVIStreamRelease(aviStream);
        AVIFileRelease(aviFile);
        return;
    }

    // Запись кадров в AVI файл
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        BYTE frameData[640 * 480 * 3] = { 0 }; // Пример данных кадра (черный кадр)
        if (AVIStreamWrite(aviStream, i, 1, frameData, sizeof(frameData), 0, NULL, NULL) != 0) {
            std::cerr << "Не удалось записать кадр в AVI файл." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Освобождение ресурсов
    AVIStreamRelease(aviStream);
    AVIFileRelease(aviFile);
    AVIFileExit();
}

int main() {
    CreateAVIFile("output.avi");
    return 0;
}

